energy gradient of Hatree Fock energy in optimal damping algorithm
In the original paper of ODA, the gradient of RHF energy (given several lines below Eq. (1)) is $E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D]=\mathrm{Tr}\{(2h+G[D])D\}$. By the spirit of ODA, we are interested in:
$$
\begin{align}
E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D+\lambda\Delta D] &= \mathrm{Tr}\{(2h+G[D+\lambda\Delta D])(D+\lambda\Delta D)\} \\
&= E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D]+\lambda(\mathrm{Tr}\{2h\cdot\Delta D\}+\mathrm{Tr}\{G[D]\cdot\Delta D\}+\mathrm{Tr}\{G[\Delta D]\cdot D\})+\lambda^2(G[\Delta D]\cdot\Delta D) \\
&= E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D]+2\lambda(\mathrm{Tr}\{h\cdot\Delta D\}+\mathrm{Tr}\{G[D]\cdot\Delta D\})+\lambda^2(G[\Delta D]\cdot\Delta D) \\
&= E^{\mathrm{RHF}}[D]+2\lambda(\mathrm{Tr}\{F[D]\cdot\Delta D\})+\lambda^2(G[\Delta D]\cdot\Delta D),
\end{align}
$$
where I have used $\mathrm{Tr}\{G[D]D^\prime\}=\mathrm{Tr}\{G[D^\prime]D\}$ and $F[D]\equiv h+G[D]$. This is discrepant with the derivation of $s$ and $c$ in Section (4.1), where $s$ should be multiplied by 2 according to the derivation above.
Is the original derivation wrong? Any help is warmly welcomed.

I believe you are correct. In a follow up paper by one of the authors, they write $s$ with the factor of 2 you have.

Unrelated, but questions like this are also a good fit on the Matter Modeling SE
